# changing user control dynamically in wpf application

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two user controls which needs to be loaded dynamically based on a property in the database.

I am modifying an existing `XAML` page. The page contains the following line

```
 <wcontrols:page1  x:Name="page1" Width="674" Height="372.215"Canvas.Left="57" Canvas.  Top="215.785" Loaded="page1_Loaded_1" />
```

I want to switch between page1 with page2 dynamically. Should i need to move the code into the code-behind file or is there any way to do that within the `XAML` file?

Comment: Show the container of Page1 control plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a style for the control and put in it a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) that set the page 2 at the change of a property of the viewmodel

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=property}" Value="page1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content" Value="{StaticResource page1}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Biniding="{Binding Path=property}" Value="page2">
                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content" Value="{StaticResource page2}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Please, fix a typo in the 'Binding' (has got an extra 'i'). It took me 5 min to realise why it can't compile a "correct" code :)